# Weblogic administration console way too slow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, weblogic

I've installed weblogic 10.3.3, configured simple domain with default configuration. And after starting weblogic I cannot use it via admin console because it is starting too slow (~10 mins). It seems that admin console application is being deployed incorrectly. Even when I enable 'staging' mode in AdminConsole deployment options, it does not help. Does anybody have a solution for this problem? It really bugs me out.

---

Configuration properties:

**Server:** [Dell PowerEdge r410 server](http://www.dell.com/us/en/highered/Servers/server-poweredge-r410/pd.aspx?refid=server-poweredge-r410&cs=RC956904&s=hied#reviews) (Six-core Intel®  Xeon® x64 CPU, 8GB RAM)

**OS:** Ubuntu Maverick 10.10 x86_64

**Weblogic:** 10.3.3 x64 (used wls1033_generic.jar file for installation)

**Java:**: 1.6.0_17_i586 (tried with different jdk's including x64, but it does not work either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out weblogic uses random number generator during startup. Because of the bug in java it reads random bits from `/dev/random`. There are almost no problems with `/dev/random` except that it is extremely slow. It takes sometimes 10 minutes or more to generate one number. Simple solution exists – using `/dev/urandom` instead. It is not that good as `/dev/random`, but at least it is instant.
Java somehow maps `/dev/urandom` file to `/dev/random`. That’s why default settings in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` are useless, they just do not make any sense.

Problem fix is very simple – adding string `export JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"` to the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. Usage of `/dev/./urandom` instead of simple `/dev/urandom` is another hack. JVM does not understand the option value otherwise.

Be aware of this problem if you try to setup weblogic under UNIX-based OS.